# iOS add view on button click

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, view

i have added 2 views in my .xib file. Both are declareted in .h file.

I also added a button. I want to active a second view, on button click.

I created an action

```
-(IBAction) selectBerufView    {
    [self addSubview: berufView];
}
```

but it returns an error

the .h File contains

```
IBOutlet UIView *berufView;
```

Comment: What is the error? Is "berufView" one of the views? Is the outlet set for the view? We'll need some more information! :)

Comment: he buids successful, but on click he aborts. yes berufView is on of views, an outlet is setted, IBOutlet UIView *berufView; i think :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[self.view addSubview: berufView];
```

Answer (score 2):

`IBAction` is usually declared in a viewcontroller. `self` would then refer to an instance of a `UIViewController` subclass. If this is your case, try `[self.view addSubview:berufView]`.